# How do I record video from my MacBook Air's webcam?

Tags: linux-mint, drivers, camera, recording

I recently installed Linux Mint on my MacBook Air, and I would like to record video from it's built in camera. It seems that the drivers are not installed, since guvcview gives an error when I try to use it. How do I install the drivers for my camera?

Output of `sudo lsusb`:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05ac:0291 Apple, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 05ac:828f Apple, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0a5c:4500 Broadcom Corp. BCM2046B1 USB 2.0 Hub (part of BCM2046 Bluetooth)
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 046d:0a44 Logitech, Inc. Headset H390
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: What error do you get ? Since i don't own a MacBook Air, what kind of camera is it ?

Comment: I'm not sure what camera I have, but it's the built in camera above the screen.
The error is `Guvcview error no video device found`

Comment: sudo lsusb will tell you about your USB hardware. Cameras are usually USB devices.

Comment: I added the output of `sudo lsusb` to my question. I don't think the camera is a USB device, as it is built in to the computer.